# How to retrieve customer form fields in BigCommerce using the API

Tags: bigcommerce

I have customer form fields in BigCommerce that are filled out when a customer creates an account.

I am trying to extract customers using the API. I can extract the form fields using the Export functionality on the site, however I can't seem to find how to extract the form field data using the API.

Is there a way? I'm guessing from the lack of information in the API docs that the answer is no, and I realise it would be difficult to implement, but it sort of defeats the purpose of having the fields if we can't extract them, and I'd rather not go back to text files.

Answer (score 1):

the stuff that API call returns vs export seem to be pretty straight forward for conversion. Is there anything specific you are looking for.

From the export functionality

```
<Customer_ID><![CDATA[1]]></Customer_ID>
<First_Name><![CDATA[Random ]]></First_Name>
<Last_Name><![CDATA[Joe Bob]]></Last_Name>
 <Company><![CDATA[]]></Company>
<Email><![CDATA[random.joebob@example.com]]></Email>
<Phone><![CDATA[252-101-2010]]></Phone>
<Notes><![CDATA[]]></Notes>
<Store_Credit><![CDATA[0.00]]></Store_Credit>
 <Customer_Group><![CDATA[]]></Customer_Group>
<Date_Joined><![CDATA[13/11/2012]]></Date_Joined>
<Addresses>
</Addresses>
<Receive_Marketing_Emails><![CDATA[0]]></Receive_Marketing_Emails>
```

From the API call

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "company": "",
        "first_name": "Random ",
        "last_name": "Joe Bob",
        "email": "random.joebob@example.com",
        "phone": "252-101-2010",
        "date_created": "Tue, 13 Nov 2012 21:16:41 +0000",
        "date_modified": "Tue, 13 Nov 2012 21:16:41 +0000",
        "store_credit": "0.0000",
        "registration_ip_address": "50.58.18.2",
        "customer_group_id": 0,
        "notes": "",
        "addresses": {
            "url": "https://store-bwvr466.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/customers/1/addresses.json",
            "resource": "/customers/1/addresses"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can get all the standard fields - what I want are the CUSTOM fields that I have created for them to enter.

Comment: @Saran Did you find how to get those custom fields?